# Loop through 30K+ rows in groups/blocks of 10 or 100s

Tags: python, list

I've got a very long list of items, 30K+.
I would like to loop through the entire list, but in groups/blocks of 10 or 100s.

So:

```
for 100items in 30Klist:
    print 100items # list of 100 items from the long list
```

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Do you mean "**pairs** of 10 or 100s"? Or just "groups/bocks of 10 or 100s"?

Comment: I can imagine you can use simple for loop with range, and array slicing for this

Comment: Sorry, groups/blocks, not pairs.